# How to get over "Cannot fetch into text, ntext, and image variables." on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, cursor

I'm getting this error message:
*Msg 16927, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetWfGenProcessParameters, Line 21
Cannot fetch into text, ntext, and image variables.*

I realy need to make this cursor work with text data.
Is there any way to get over this error?

Comment: you would need to cast to a varchar and possibly lose text if it's really long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server 2005`, you can use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`:

```
CREATE TABLE text_test (test NTEXT NOT NULL)

INSERT
INTO    text_test
VALUES  ('test')

DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE txt_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT test
        FROM   text_test

OPEN    txt_cur

FETCH   NEXT
FROM    txt_cur
INTO    @t

CLOSE txt_cur

DEALLOCATE txt_cur
GO

DROP TABLE text_test
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

FIrst, why are you using a cusrsor, cursors are to be avoided at all costs. If you use a set-based solution maybe your problem will go away. However without more of an idea as to what you are trying to do inteh cursor, it is hard to provide advice. Certainly I can't change the fact that SQL Server does not let you put text data into a variable. When you meet a system limitation, you need to rethink what you are doing and how you are doing it.

Comment: I'm working with some XML fields, stored as NTEXT. And I need a NTEXT variable to work with *sp_xml_preparedocument* without chuncking the xml.

Comment: Cursors should not be avoided 'at all costs'.  There are times when you need to use a cursor when they come in handy and saves significant development time or data migration time.  Sometimes I need to execute a stored procedure one time to do something where a cursor is the fastest way to get it done.  Saying they should be avoided at all costs is only true if cost is not an issue, but for me and what I do, it saves a lot of time and makes me more efficient.  With that said, I would agree that cursors should try to be avoided... but not at all costs.

Comment: @bunggo, cursors to save development time is a very7 poor practice. Database time is FAR more valuable than dev time. Yes there are times to use cursors, but they should virtually never be used except by an experienced dba and NEVER by an application developer because he is too lazy or stupid to learn how to do things correctly. Incidently the set based solutions are generally shorter and take less time to develop.

Comment: Database time is not always more valuable than dev time. Maybe for you it is, but not for me it isn't. There are many times when my clients want to get data mined from their database just one time and don't care how it is done. Sometimes the fastest way I can do it is with a cursor. With deadlines and cost caps, sometimes that is what has to be be done even if it isn't ideal to make the customer happy. I agree with what you say as a guideline, but not as a rule. As an app developer (and DBA), we need to use the tools available to us to best solve problems, and sometimes that is a cursor.

Comment: cursors actually take longer to write than set-based code once you knwo what you are doing.